# Filter and fetch using select_related and prefetch_related in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Here are my below models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField('city name', max_length=25)

class Pincode(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='city_pincode')
    pincode = models.PositiveIntegerField('pincode', unique=True)

class Vendors(models.Model):
    pincode = models.ManyToManyField(Pincode, related_name='pincode_vendor')
    shop_name = models.CharField('Shop name(English)', max_length=50)

class SubCategory(models.Model):    
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_subcategory')
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendors, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vendor_subcategory')

class ItemGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=50, unique=True, blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subcategory_item')
    itemgroup = models.ForeignKey(ItemGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='itemgroup_item')
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=255)
```

I am trying to fetch all the subcategories using fields itemgroup and pincode from models Item and Itemgroup.

Here is my code:

```
SubCategory.objects.filter(vendor__pincode__pincode=500071).prefetch_related(Prefetch('subcategory_item',
            queryset=Item.objects.filter(itemgroup__name='Biryanis')
        ))
```

Here is i am getting all the items in the subcategory model. But i want only those subcategories whose itemgroup='Biryanis' and pincode='500071'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding `select_related` and `prefetch_related`. These two methods are used only to gain performance by minimizing database calls.

Your code does not perform filter on the subcategory_item. Use the following code to do so.

```
SubCategory.objects.filter(vendor__pincode__pincode=500071).filter(subcategory_item__itemgroup__name='Biryanis')
```

---

#### If your question was about performance:

Using `select_related` and `prefetch_related` will not benefit you if you are calling the database once. And there are there some disadvantages in using those methods. Make sure you read the QuerySet [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just small change in the code SubCategory.objects.filter(vendor__pincode__pincode=500071).filter(subcategory_item__itemgroup__name='Biryanis'). This works fine now.